# Symfony2: Sticky language does not stick always

Tags: php, symfony, session, locale

I have weird problem, that never happened before.  The sticky language does not working always.

Its starts working for a while when doing these steps:

1. go to dev environment
2. click to profiler
3. go back to dev enviroment
4. switch language
5. go to production enviroment

Viola, the sticky language now works.

I have tried several ways, googled, stackoverflowed, used own brain to customize language handling in tons of different ways. For example set a custom session variable then based on its value I have tried to set request language and also language to session. But as soon as page loads, this native session variable is lost including request parameters.

Here is my current LocateListener witch works as described above:

```
class LocateListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

private $defaultLocale;

public function __construct($defaultLocale = 'sk')
{
    $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
}

public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    if (!$request->hasPreviousSession())
    {
        return;
    }

    // try to see if the locale has been set as a _locale routing parameter
    if ($locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale'))
    {
        $request->getSession()->set('_locale', $locale);
       // echo "locale changed";
    }
    else
    {
        // if no explicit locale has been set on this request, use one from the session
        $request->setLocale($request->getSession()->get('_locale', $this->defaultLocale));
        $request->getSession()->set('_last_locale_url', $actual_link = "http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    }
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
        // must be registered before the default Locale listener
        KernelEvents::REQUEST => array(array('onKernelRequest', 17)),
    );
}

}
```

The controller action that handles language switch:

```
public function switchlangAction(Request $req)
{
    return $this->redirect($req->headers->get("referer"));
}
```

The routing:

```
erik_app_switchlang:
path:      /locale/{_locale}
defaults: { _controller: ErikAppBundle:Default:switchlang }
requirements:
    _locale:  sk|en
```

The session configuration:

```
    session:
    cookie_domain: netlime.tk
    cookie_lifetime:         3600 
    cookie_httponly:         false
```

The way how locale listener is registered

```
app.locale_listener:
    class: Erik\AppBundle\Service\LocateListener
    arguments: ["%kernel.default_locale%"]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber, priority: 17 }
```

The website I am talking about is https://www.netlime.tk app_dev is allowed, you can try it if required. http://tvarplast.sk website runs on same sticky language code and there it works.

Netlime runs on custom vps on digital ocean with comodo certificate.

Thank you!

**--- EDIT --**

This is my security file

```
security:
encoders:
    Erik\UserBundle\Entity\User: 
        algorithm:          md5
        iterations:        0
        encode_as_base64:   false

providers:
    user_db:
        entity: { class: ErikUserBundle:User, property: email }

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        provider: user_db
        form_login:
            login_path:     /account/signin
            check_path:    /account/signin/check
        logout:
            path:   /account/signout
            target: /
        security:     true
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/account/edit, roles: [ROLE_USER,ROLE_COMPANY,ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN,ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN] }
    - { path: ^/admin, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN,ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN] }
    - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: The problem is you have not PHPSESSID for anonymous user. Check you security file and PHP config.

Comment: Thank you, I have figured out from your answer that I does not used the alerts block that starts session automatically when its accessing for fleshbags. Please post your answer as Answer question and I will accept it.